# Разное значение функции $.height() в разное время

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Прогуглил - не помогло, прогуглил на английском - тоже не помогло, пришел на добрый старый Stackoverflow. Итак, сразу к делу. Структура верстки такая:

```
<div class="header">
  <div>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img style="height: 100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Я пытаюсь получить высоту `.header` самым обычным

```
console.log(
  $('.header').height()
);
```

И вот тут то самое интересное: если я вставляю эту функцию в обычный `<script>` внутри функции `$(document).ready(function () {});`, то в консоль выводится значение больше реального. Если введу выше указанный код в консоль браузера после того как страница загрузилась, то выдает действительное.

---

В результате длительного гугления выяснил, что это особенность вызванная  свойством `line-height`, который, насколько я понял, высчитывается после готовности DOM. И дело в том, что шрифт у меня подключенный, на дефолтной "Гельветике" все работает должным образом. **Задача**, *насколько я понимаю*, **вызвать эту функцию после просчета `line-height`**. А еще ради подтверждения источника проблемы решил `line-height` приравнять к `0`, и вуаля - тоже все работает. Помогите. Надеюсь доходчиво описал проблему.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что проблема в картинке, которая находится внутри блока `.header`, а не в `line-height`. Попробуйте задать ей фиксированную высоту в пикселях через атрибут `height` или просто удалить её.

Comment: @terron к сожалению уже пытался, и не помогло(

Comment: Тогда попробуйте засунуть подсчет размера блока не в  `$(document).ready(function () {/* ... */});`, а в `window.onload = function() { /* ... */ };` - сработает только когда все ассеты, включая ваш шрифт, загрузятся.

Comment: @igolka97 "That is a lucid, intelligent, well thought-out question." - Judge Chamberlain Haller "My Cousin Vinny". Сожалею, что могу проголосовать за Ваш вопрос только один раз.

Comment: @terron удивительно, насколько ответ может находиться на поверхности - и как я только сам не додумался. Оформите, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий в виде ответа, и я отмечу его как решение.

Comment: @Igor спасибо:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для изображений, чтобы вёрстка не "скакала", следует указывать фиксированные размеры через атрибуты `width` и `height`.

Также, если вы используете подключаемые шрифты, то следует дождаться их полной загрузки. Используемый вами `$(document).ready(function () {/* ... */});` срабатывает только при полной загрузке DOM, что не гарантирует загрузку ассетов (шрифтов, стилей, изображений, и т.п.) и айфреймов.

Добиться желаемого результата можно двумя способами:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { /* ... */ });
```

... или ...

```
window.onload = function () { /* ... */ };
```

Первый вариант предпочтительнее как минимум потому, что на странице можно будет создать множество событий, срабатывающих при загрузке страницы, в то время как второй вариант может быть использован лишь единожды. Если есть желание детальнее взвесить плюсы и минусы обоих подходов, рекомендую ознакомиться с ответом на этот вопрос: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494)